# Rxjs Observable gets <unknown> type assigned when to many taps piped. Why is that?

Tags: rxjs

I noticed that if i pipe many taps an observable gets unknown type assigned. **Why is that?**

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-h5oy9m?file=index.ts) example. If you comment/uncomment a tap you will see the test$ observable being assigned an unknown type.

```
import { of, Observable, combineLatest, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, shareReplay, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface Test {
  key1: string;
}

const _selectedId = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

const test$: Observable<Test[]> = combineLatest([_selectedId]).pipe(
  filter(([id]) => !!id),
  switchMap(([id]) => httpCall()),
  tap((test) => console.log(test)), //ADD OR REMOVE A TAP TO TRIGGER TYPE ERROR
  tap((test) => console.log(test)),
  tap((test) => console.log(test)),
  tap((test) => console.log(test)),
  tap((test) => console.log(test)),
  tap((test) => console.log(test)),
  tap((test) => console.log(test)),
  shareReplay(1)
);

const httpCall = (): Observable<Test[]> => {
  return of([{ key1: 'testing1' }]);
};

_selectedId.next('test');

test$.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: It's not because of the tap operator. It's due to the type definition of the pipe method. It only has "real" overloads up to 9 operators. You can check it by commenting or adding any other operator.

Comment: I think right now, *TypeScript*'s mechanisms that would allow a properly recursive type for `pipe` are rather slow. Instead, RxJS just uses overloads (multiple functions with the same name, distinguished by their types). Which means there's a limit to how many operators you have have withing a `pipe` before inference stops. 

There's a workaround. You can just chain `pipe`. For example `pipe(o(1),o(2),o(3)).pipe(o(4),o(5))` That second pipe is redundant, but it'll let the RxJS's type defs for TypeScript work as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at how `pipe` is defined in [Observable.ts](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/4afbc16f053ffbfbd4f45d677056ff00d7711de7/src/internal/Observable.ts#L348) :

```
pipe(): Observable<T>;
pipe<A>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>): Observable<A>;
pipe<A, B>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>): Observable<B>;
pipe<A, B, C>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>): Observable<C>;
pipe<A, B, C, D>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>): Observable<D>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>): Observable<E>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>): Observable<F>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>): Observable<G>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>): Observable<H>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>, op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>): Observable<I>;
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>, op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>, ...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]): Observable<unknown>;
```

As you can see the last definition

```
pipe<A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I>(op1: OperatorFunction<T, A>, op2: OperatorFunction<A, B>, op3: OperatorFunction<B, C>, op4: OperatorFunction<C, D>, op5: OperatorFunction<D, E>, op6: OperatorFunction<E, F>, op7: OperatorFunction<F, G>, op8: OperatorFunction<G, H>, op9: OperatorFunction<H, I>, ...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]): Observable<unknown>;
```

There is a spread operator `...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]` which will allow to have as any parameters you want and will return `Observable<unknown>`.

So the `pipe` method support up to 9 operator functions with the right return type and after it will just return `unknown` if you add one more !

Comment: Also noticed that in earlier versions of rxjs like 6.2.2 it didn't return unknown:
```pipe<R>(...operations: OperatorFunction<any, any>[]): Observable<R>;```

More info about the reason of the change here:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/3945